# Declare Math Operator

Tags: feature-request

For some times I've faced the problem with an absence of an operator `\argmax` and one should use `arg\max` which is not nice. Usually in LaTeX one uses `DeclareMathOperator`. In [MathJaX help](http://www.math.harvard.edu/texman/) on the right side of the page this operator is also described - but it doesn't work when you try to write the post on the site. Is it possible to fix it?

Answer (score 12):

The `\DeclareMathOperator` macro makes the argument a math operator with limits above and below. This can be achieved on an ad-hoc basis by using the `\mathop{...}` command, which turns what is inside the declaration into a mathoperator, followed by the `\limits` command, which will place limits above and below (in essence, you are just typing out what the `DeclareMathOperator` does).

So, for example, you can do `$\mathop{\arg\,\max}\limits_x$` to produce $\mathop{\arg\,\max}\limits_x$.

I know it's a chore and not necessarily a good solution, but at least you get a good outcome. (Also, I suspect that enabling macros like `\DeclareMathOperator` occurs at the Mathjax level, rather than the stackexchange level, but I could be wrong).

Comment: It seems to me that you're right and thanks anyway for the solution. On the other hand, `Declare[...]` is presented in MathJaX help (which indeed seems to be just a LaTeX howto) - that's why I thought that it's realized in MathJaX.

Comment: @Gortaur: Well, for me the `\DeclareMathOperator` environment works. You just have to make sure you put it *inside* a math environment (that is, between `$` or `$$` or `\\[`) so that it can be seen by the MathJax engine.

Comment: @Theo: Oh, I never bothered to test it. There you go.

Comment: @Gortaur: I use them sparingly because I'm not sure about the scope (it certainly affects the entire post, but it might be the entire page) and I don't want to mess with other posts. It produces some ugly spacing where insertet, so I usually put declarations at the end of a paragraph if I really need them.

Comment: Ok, thank you .

Comment: Put a \! between the \arg and \max to get rid of that ugly space.